# mod_wsgi End of script output before headers

Tags: mod-wsgi

I have a problem with my web application. Sometimes when people upload an image (seems to happen with large image only), I have mod_wsgi who crash with this message :

```
End of script output before headers: wsgi.py, referer:http:::...
Process 'wsgi' has died, restarting.
Process 'wsgi' terminated by signal 9
```

and so an internal error is raised.

Here is my wsgi file:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and here is the wsgi conf file

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:80>

Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/static/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/wsgi.py


<Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
  python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages user=wsgi group=wsgi \
  home=/opt/python/current/app
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Do you know what is the problem and what I can do to solve it ?

Please note that I cannot migrate to nginx and gunicorn.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What version of mod_wsgi are you using? Does your system run a monitor which will kill processes if they use too much memory? Have you monitored the memory usage of the processes to see if they are growing to a very large value? Can you upgrade to the latest mod_wsgi version and try again?

Comment: Hello, version I use is `mod24_wsgi-py27.x86_64, 3.4-8.14.amzn1`, I have tried to update, but it seems to be the last one. When monitoring with top, I do not see any over usage of memory :(

Comment: Set 'LogLevel info' in the Apache configuration. This will cause mod_wsgi to log messages about why daemon processes are being restarted. This ail show whether the kill -9 is coming about because of a restart somehow triggered by mod_wsgi, or some external monitoring service. So change the Apache log level and then capture mod_wsgi log messages leading up to and after the messages you originally quoted.

Comment: The messages I originally quoted were already with info log level.

Comment: Can you provide greater context from the log so it is possible to see messages before and after that point then related to that event in time?

Comment: Do you have settings.py file? Can you start python interactive session and run commands:


    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    application = get_wsgi_application()

Comment: You absoutely need to supply apache with an error log.